# Dist Upgrade Using Installation Media?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

How can I do a dist-upgrade using the installation media? I have it on a flash drive (This is Kubuntu). I don't want to have to download the update for all my machines. I want to download once and install everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do a dist-upgrade using the installation media?

You can't. The only method from the installation media is a complete install.

> I want to download once and install everywhere.

Install [Puppetmaster](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html). That let's you define all your machines in your network as slaves and you can update, upgrade, administer those slaves. You can also administer your users, lock them out, create new ones, change passwords and lots more.